# Partitions created outside BIDS

Tags: ssas

In my cube, partition creation and processing is automated. Now, if I make any change to the cube structure through BIDS, while deploying the changes it will delete all the partitions which are not defined in the cube. Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Could you create a new solution in bids by importing from your server? That way any partition definitions will be present along with any new changes you make.

Comment: so that means whenever I want to make any changes to my cube, I have to create a new solution by importing it from the server
?

Answer (score 0):

BIDS normally works with local files. Each deployment overwrites the structure on the server with the version you have in your local files.

If you do structural changes on the server independently from BIDS that you want to keep, but add changes in BIDS, you can just get the current state of the server structure back to local files by selecting File/New/Project/Business Intelligence Projects/Import Analysis Services Database. Make sure you set the project settings as required in the bottom of the dialog before hitting the OK button.

Another possibility to work with BIDS is in online mode: In this mode, BIDS does not work on local files, but directly on the structure as it is on the server. To use this mode, select File/Open/Analysis Services Database, and select the server and database you want to open. Some menu entries in BIDS change, and each time you hit the "Save" toolbar icon or its menu counterpart, the changes are directly written to the server structure. Note however, that you will not have a local copy of the database structure in this case, which means that e. g. version controlling your Analysis Services database structure is impossible.

Comment: The only problem I'm facing is with the Partitions that are automatically created on the Server. Now, whenever I've to make any structural change in the cube, I've to first manually create all the new partitions , and then deploy the cube,. Is there any work around?

Comment: As I wrote, either import the current version of the cube structure including the partitions to a new project. Or, just open the cube in online mode and do your structural changes in this mode.